# Debug Assertion

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I have receiving an error like "*Debug Assertion Failed*" message when the debug comes to the line  "*valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 256)*" When I press ignore button, I see exception

"*Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCAC2EAFAC (ucrtbased.dll) in soketSample.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal*"

My Code is below;

```
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <MSWSock.h>
#include <share.h>
#include <atltypes.h>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[256] = {};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";

    WSADATA Data;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Data);

    //Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)& opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to set the SO_REUSEADDR option");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    address.sin_port = htons(30035);

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 5) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    
    Sleep(3000);
    valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 256); ****

    send(new_socket, "Hello, world!\n", 13, 0);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    
    return 0; 

}
```

what is wrong in my code,  could you help me?

Comment: The line `printf("%s\n", buffer);` will be causing undefined behavior if `buffer` is not null terminated. If the function call `read` does indeed read 256 bytes, then `buffer` is not guaranteed to be null terminated. However, based on your description, this is not the cause of your problem, because you say that your problem occurs two lines earlier.

Comment: Exactly, I have already erased that line and try it. Again I am taking the same error.

Comment: It starts listening, that is ok, but when you connect with client, it starts to read and give the  error.

Comment: `int server_fd, new_socket, [...]` is wrong. The correct data type is `SOCKET`, which is 4 bytes for 32-bit applications and 8 bytes for 64-bit applications. Therefore, for 64-bit applications, the data type is not large enough, as `int` is always 4 bytes long.

Comment: Did you verify that `new_socket` has a correct value?  The `accept` function actually returns a `SOCKET`, which is a UINT_PTR (64-bit).  This is why you must use the correct types for return values, and not just make them up using wrong assumptions.

Comment: Actually I have checked out all socket c++ coding samples. In all samples, the data type is declared as int. Maybe they are for 32bit applications.  I have declared the data type as long, Again I am taking the same error. Do you have code samples with socket type.

Comment: @Swiftworker: On the Windows platform, the data type `long` is also only 4 bytes. You must use the data type `long long` to get 8 bytes. Also, those data type are signed, whereas a `SOCKET` is unsigned. Therefore, I strongly suggest that you use the correct data type.

Comment: @Swiftworker -- What difficulty are you having in simply declaring `SOCKET new_socket;` and using it?

Comment: @Swiftworker: The coding samples you read were probably for POSIX sockets. They are not compatible with Windows Sockets 2. If you are looking for code examples for Windows Sockets 2, you might want to look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/getting-started-with-winsock) to to the official Microsoft documentation.

Comment: @Swiftworker Yes, Winsock and POSIX has differences.  If you want cross platform, then use boost or similar library.

Comment: @Swiftworker: Even if Windows Sockets 2 and POSIX sockets are not compatible, they are very similar. Most of your code should work. As far as I can tell, the only change necessary is to change `int` to `SOCKET`. Also, I am not sure if setting `SO_REUSEADDR` using `setsockopt` is supported on Windows Sockets 2, but that shouldn't matter in this case. I also believe that using `perror` will not work with Windows Sockets, as you should use [`WSAGetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror) instead.

Comment: Thanks, for all help.. yes it has worked with winsock2 . I have done,  bind, accept, send and receive commands,     thanks again for saving my time..